# Monitor process' file access by file and access speed

Tags: linux, performance, monitoring

I have multiple disks in my system sometimes I have a heavy read usage on my root partition. I know that there are some processes reading a lot of data, but from all disks. How can I find out which process is accessing which file?

I've tried htop, dstat or iotop. However these seem not to be able to show activity by process and file. In windows ressource monitor does this job perfect:

[image]

I can't imagine that there isn't a similar console tool for linux.

Answer (score 0):

The tool you are looking for is `atop`.

`atop` can be used to interactively view the current disk, memory, network and all other major details of processes.

`atop` also supports being run as a service capturing all data to a compressed logfile, for example capturing all processes statistics with a 1 minute interval:

```
atop -a -w ~/atop_current 60
```

Then reading it back

```
atop -r ~/atop_current
```

To switch to "disk" view you can press `d` while running on an interactive console.

You can then browse back and forwards in time using `t` and `T` (upper and lower case). Current "time interval" will be shown at the top of the screen.

In any given "interval" I see something like this, showing how much data the process wrote, how much it read and so on.

```
   RDDSK    WRDSK       WCANCL    DSK     CMD 
   8192K    2304K       0K        100%    Proc1
      0K      32K       0K        0%      Proc2
      0K       0K       0K        0%      Proc3
      0K       0K       0K        0%      Proc4
```

Answer (score 0):

For a different perspective, which might work for you, you can use **auditctl** to log accesses to specific directories (of course, you can do it for root dir `/` if you really want to).

For example, on Ubuntu you can get it with

`sudo apt-get install auditd audispd-plugins`

Edit the config file at `nano /etc/audit/auditd.conf` if you want to specify the log location.

Now you need to add rules saying what you want to monitor. Try to make them as restrictive as possible, there can be a lot of things going on in a file system… I suggest something like this (adapt to your paths, of course):

`auditctl -a exit,always -F dir=/home -F perm=rwa`

Don't forget to disable when done:

`auditctl -D`

Now your log should list all accesses, with **pid** of process responsible for it.